# Time and expense registration tracking tool

Tags: web, time-management, accounting

I am currently using a program named [WorkBook](http://workbook.dk/) - and am now looking for a cheaper replacement. Preferable free - open source software!

I only use the time registration and expense registration parts of the system for my customers so that parts will be important to us!

I have been trying TimeLog - but I am not sure whether it would fit our needs in the future and would be a good substitution.

What else is out there? And what would you please recommend?

We are less than 10 users. We are only interested in web solutions (not Windows-solutions)!

Looking forward to your answers - kind regards Rikke

Answer (score 4):

This page has helped me in the past

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_time_tracking_software

There are a number of apps there that you can take a look at, from free to subscriptions based.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you SO much - my first answer in here ;) ....any one at the wikipedia list in particular you have had a good experience with? KR Rikke